Using clang-format over tramp
I have clang installed in a docker container which I'm able to interact with in emacs through tramp. The motivation is to replicate a dev-container like environment in emacs. As much as possible, at any rate (as per this post).
I can access the docker container's filesystem through the path /docker:container_name:/path/to/file. I'm using the clang-format package in emacs, which allows me to run clang-format on buffers. I'd like it to use the clang-format binary installed in the container. By default, it will look on my local filesystem, so have fiddled with the clang-format.el. It used to read:
(defcustom clang-format-executable
  (or (executable-find "clang-format")
      "clang-format")
  "Location of the clang-format executable.
   A string containing the name or the full path of the executable."
  :group 'clang-format
  :type '(file :must-match t)
  :risky t)

and have bodged it to the following:
(defcustom clang-format-executable "/docker:container_name:/usr/bin/clang-format"
  "Location of the clang-format executable.
   A string containing the name or the full path of the executable."
  :group 'clang-format
  :type '(file :must-match t)
  :risky t)

But when trying to run clang-format in a buffer, I get:
apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, /docker:container_name:/usr/bin/clang-format

Clearly I'm doing something stupid, but I'm sort of out of ideas at this point.

If your using an lsp server, like in the linked post, eg. clangd, you should be able to run lsp-format-buffer or the eglot equivalent.  For the clang-format-executable I'd guess that needs to a docker exec ... since emacs isnt running in the container
